# Stop Running function jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, function

I need to stop a function in jQuery, I tried `preventStop()` but I think the syntax is wrong, this is the code:

```
function changeColor(curNumber){
        curNumber++;

        if(curNumber > 3){
            curNumber = 1;
        }

        $('body').removeClass().addClass('bgColor' + curNumber);
        setTimeout(function(){changeColor(curNumber)}, 600);
}
    changeColor(0);
```

As you can see, I'm changing the class, now, I want to stop that action if the user clicks over the document

```
$('body').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
```

Something like that didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a timer ID:

```
var timer = null;

function changeColor(curNumber) {
    ...

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        changeColor(curNumber)
    }, 600);
}
```

You can clear it with `clearTimeout`:

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    if (timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
})
```

Comment: This make the trick! i only changed $('body') for $('html')! So much thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to stop the changing of the colors, then you could do that like this by remembering the current timer in a variable and then stopping it:

```
var timer;
function changeColor(curNumber){
    curNumber++;

    if(curNumber > 3){
        curNumber = 1;
    }

    $('body').removeClass().addClass('bgColor' + curNumber);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){changeColor(curNumber)}, 600);
}
changeColor(0);

$('body').click(function(event){
    clearTimeout(timer);
})
```

You can then start it again by calling `changeColor()` again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `return false;` to achieve that.

Whenever we use return false then the control will return.The other statements will not execute.That is to the event will  not file.

Comment: Though it answers the question, please explain it clearly. (avoid single line answers)

Comment: Also, whenever you answer with a one liner, not only do you make it harder for the original poster to understand your answer, you're also triggering an automatic Review which makes users like Mr_Green and myself go through it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.Form next time on wards i will make it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You should use `setInterval` in place of `setTimeout` for recurring events.
2. Both of those functions return a value which can be passed to `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval` respectively.

If you call `setInterval` in an outer scope and store its return value somewhere accessible, you could bind the click event to call `clearInterval` with that value to stop the recurring callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.finish();` -- http://api.jquery.com/finish/ -- to stop a function running. Not sure whether this is the best practice or not, since it is basically intended to control `Effects`, but it is work well for me:

**Your code would become like this**

```
$('body').click(function(event){
        event.finish();
    })
```

This is an example that simulate how `.finish()` stop a function from running after comparing inputs' values.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3sn/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

or you can try with

```
$('body').click(function(event){
    return false;
})
```